# given `logger -t specificUser` how do filter tail by that tag? (tail -f ??? specificUser)

Tags: tail, logger

if i'm tagging my logs with -t, how do i filter my log searches for that specific tag?

given:

```
logger -t specificUser
```

show it (in real time) with

```
tail -f ???? specificUser
```

Comment: Tried to pipe it through `grep`? Might need to experiment with buffering...

Comment: Given that your syslog configuration could direct those messages to any various file, I think the first step would be finding the right file(s). Are you always sending to the same facility with the same priority?

Comment: @JeffSchaller you're 100% right, I should be piping to another log file. thank you!